# How do scripts communicate with banks?

Tags: web-services, api, e-commerce

What options exist to facilitate payments to banks or credit card companies?  Are there programmatic APIs for banks that, say, perform the same actions as paypal might?  I'm looking for libraries or options that aren't through an existing provider; that could be developed on their own.

Basically, lately I've become interested in ecommerce and I'm wondering how the communication between a website and a bank or credit card company is made.

I've looked around a bit, but I'm not really sure about the terminology in the field; any resources you could point me at, or good books about the subject would be awesome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a merchant account with a bank, then sign up with a merchant processor like [Cybersource](http://www.cybersource.com/) or [Litle](http://www.litle.com/). The merchant processor provides an webservice API to process authorizations, payments, credits, and voids. You implement the processor's API and then you can do online payments. They act as a go-between for you and the credit card company. You're not likely going to get permission to communicate directly with the credit card's network.

Maybe use [this link](http://www.ourshop.com/resources/internet-merchant-accounts.html) as a starting point. [This is cybersource's API documentation.](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/sbc/credit_cards/html/)

Comment: How does cybersource accomplish the payments?  Would it be possible to replicate the services they provide?

Comment: @lolseal Each credit card company provides their own payment network. VisaNet is the largest. You need to talk to each card company separately to get access to their network. I don't know anything about what is involved in getting access but I'm going to guess it's not so easy, hence the need for the merchant processors.